# Apache log: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, html

I have a web page that working ok in a server but in my new server is not working. The Apache Log says "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.". 
I can't fix it.

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1.css [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ $1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ $1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ $1.gif [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ $1.js [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.swf$ $1.swf [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$4&subsubcodigo=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$4&subsubcodigo=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?idioma=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those rules create an infinite loop

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1.css [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ $1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ $1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ $1.gif [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ $1.js [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.swf$ $1.swf [L]
```

and are, by the way, useless (so you can remove them).

You have also many *design* issues in your code (you can combine several rules, you can use more restrictive regex, you can avoid capturing non-needed data, etc).

Finally, your htaccess would look like this

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?[^/]*$ /index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$3&subsubcodigo=$4 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?[^/]*$ /index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2&subcodigo=$3 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?[^/]*$ /index.php?idioma=$1&codigo=$2 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?idioma=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```